# How to set the tolerance identifying changes in Variance?

Tags: r

I'm using a very good R package named "changepoint" to detect changes in the variance in my series.

At the moment i'm using **cpt.var** function, it is very powerful to detect changes BUT I would like to have a **more tolerance** method.

```
cpt.var(mod$residuals)
```

where *mod* is a linear regression:

```
mod <- lm(priceA ~ priceB)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more tolerance"?

Comment: that do not detects "small breaks"

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the help file for `?cpt.var` you can change the penalty argument from the default `SIC` to `Manual`. When using the `Manual`, you can specify a type I error value through the `value` argument.

Here is an example based on the help file:

```
# Example of multiple changes in variance at 50,100,150 in simulated data
set.seed(1)
x = c(rnorm(50,0,1), rnorm(50,0,10), rnorm(50,0,5), rnorm(50,0,1))

##Key arguments Manual and value
##Returns 4 changes points
cpt.var(x, penalty="Manual", value="log(2*log(n))", method="BinSeg", 
        dist="CSS", Q=5, class=FALSE) 

##Returns 5 changes points - a false positive
cpt.var(x, penalty="Manual", value="0.5*log(2*log(n))", method="BinSeg", 
        dist="CSS", Q=5, class=FALSE)
```